# Ignoring not supported Decodables

Tags: json, swift, enums, option-type, decodable

I've been using `Codable`s in my current project with a great pleasure - everything is fine, most of the stuff I get out of the box and it's built in - perfect! Though, recently I've stumbled on a first *real issue*, which can't be solved automatically they way I want it.

---

**Problem description**
I have a JSON coming from the backend which is a nested thing. It looks like this

```
{
    "id": "fef08c8d-0b16-11e8-9e00-069b808d0ecc",
    "title": "Challenge_Chapter",
    "topics": [
        {
            "id": "5145ea2c-0b17-11e8-9e00-069b808d0ecc",
            "title": "Automation_Topic",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "id": "518dfb8c-0b18-11e8-9e00-069b808d0ecc",
                    "title": "Automated Line examle",
                    "type": "text_image",
                    "video": null,
                    "challenge": null,
                    "text_image": {
                        "background_url": "",
                        "element_render": ""
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": "002a1776-0b18-11e8-9e00-069b808d0ecc",
                    "title": "Industry 3.0 vs. 4.0: A vision of the new manufacturing world",
                    "type": "video",
                    "video": {
                        "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx",
                        "provider": "youtube"
                    },
                    "challenge": null,
                    "text_image": null
                },
                {
                    "id": "272fc2b4-0b18-11e8-9e00-069b808d0ecc",
                    "title": "Classmarker_element",
                    "type": "challenge",
                    "video": null,
                    "challenge": {
                        "url": "https://www.classmarker.com/online-test/start/",
                        "description": null,
                        "provider": "class_marker"
                    },
                    "text_image": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Chapter** is the root object and it contains a list of **Topics** and each topic contains a list of **Elements**. Pretty straightforward, but I get stuck with the lowest level, **Elements**. Each **Element** has an enum coming from the backend, which looks like this:
`[ video, challenge, text_image ]`, but iOS app doesn't support challenges, so my **ElementType** enum in Swift looks like:

```
public enum ElementType: String, Codable {
    case textImage = "text_image"
    case video = "video"
}
```

Of, course, it `throws`, because the first thing which happens is it tries to decode `challenge` value for this enum and it's not there, so my whole decoding fails.

**What I want**
I simply want decoding process to *ignore* `Element`s which can't be decoded. I don't need any `Optional`s. I just want them not to be present in Topic's array of Elements.

**My reasoning and it's drawbacks**
Of course, I've made a couple of attempts to solve this problem. First one, and the simples one is just to marks `ElementType` as `Optional`, but with this approach later on I'll have to unwrap everything and handle this - which is rather a tedious task. My second thought was to have something like `.unsupported` case in my enum, but again, later I want to use this to generate cells and I'll have to `throw` or return `Optional` - basically, same issues as previous idea.
My last idea, but I haven't tested it yet, is to write a custom `init()` for decodable and somehow deal with it there, but I'm not sure whether it's `Element` or `Topic` which should be responsible for this? If I write it in `Element`, I can't return nothing, I'll have to `throw`, but if I put it in `Topic` I'll have to `append` successfully decoded elements to array. The thing is what will happen if at some point I will be fetching `Elements` directly - again I won't be able to do it without `throw`ing.

**TL;DR**
I want `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` not to `throw`, but to return `Optional`.

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON data?

Comment: @Gereon I've added sample JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found something about this in [SR-5953](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5953), but I think this is a hacky one.

Anyway, for the curious ones to allow this *lossy* decoding you need to manually decode everything. You can write it in you `init(from decoder: Decoder)`, but a better approach would be to write a new helper `struct` called `FailableCodableArray`. Implementation would look like:

```
struct FailableCodableArray<Element: Decodable>: Decodable {
    // https://github.com/phynet/Lossy-array-decode-swift4
    private struct DummyCodable: Codable {}

    private struct FailableDecodable<Base: Decodable>: Decodable {
        let base: Base?

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            self.base = try? container.decode(Base.self)
        }
    }

    private(set) var elements: [Element]

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        var elements = [Element]()

        if let count = container.count {
            elements.reserveCapacity(count)
        }

        while !container.isAtEnd {
            guard let element = try container.decode(FailableDecodable<Element>.self).base else {
                _ = try? container.decode(DummyCodable.self)
                continue
            }

            elements.append(element)
        }

        self.elements = elements
    }
}
```

And than for the actual decoding of those failable elements you jusy have to write a simple `init(from decoder: Decoder)` implementation like:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    elements = try container.decode(FailableCodableArray<Element>.self, forKey: .elements).elements
}
```

As I've said, this solution works fine, but it feels a little *hacky*. It's an **open** bug, so you can vote it and let the Swift team see, that something like this built in would be a nice addition!

Comment: Thanks for the bug link, that's really helpful. As an alternative for decoding JSON like this I still keep the [Marshal](https://github.com/utahiosmac/Marshal) around, which offers `discardingErrors` parameters in its API.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create an umbrella protocol for all three types

```
protocol TypeItem {}
```

**Edit: To conform to the requirement that only two types can be considered you have to use classes to get reference semantics**

Then create classes `TextImage` and `Video` and a `Dummy` class adopting the protocol. All instances of the `Dummy class` will be removed after the decoding process.

```
class TextImage : TypeItem, Decodable {
    let backgroundURL : String
    let elementRender : String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case backgroundURL = "background_url"
        case elementRender = "element_render"
    }
}

class Video : TypeItem, Decodable {
    let url : URL
    let provider : String
}

class Dummy : TypeItem {}
```

Use the enum to decode `type` properly

```
enum Type : String, Decodable {
    case text_image, video, challenge
}
```

In the struct `Element` you have to implement a custom initializer which decodes the JSON to the structs depending on the type. The unwanted `challange` type is decoded into a `Dummy` instance. Due to the umbrella protocol you need only one property.

```
class Element : Decodable {
    let type : Type
    let id : String
    let title : String
    let item : TypeItem

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, type, video, text_image
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        type = try container.decode(Type.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .text_image: item = try container.decode(TextImage.self, forKey: .text_image)
        case .video: item = try container.decode(Video.self, forKey: .video)
        default: item = Dummy()
        }
    }
}
```

Finally create a `Root` struct for the root element and `Topic` for the `topics` array. In `Topic` add a method to filter the `Dummy` instances.

```
class Root : Decodable {
    let id : String
    let title : String
    var topics : [Topic]
}

class Topic : Decodable {
    let id : String
    let title : String
    var elements : [Element]

    func filterDummy() {
        elements = elements.filter{!($0.item is Dummy)}
    }
}
```

After the decoding call `filterDummy()` in each `Topic` to remove the dead items.
Another downside is that you have to cast `item` to the static type for example

```
let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
result.topics.forEach({$0.filterDummy()})
if let videoElement = result.topics[0].elements.first(where: {$0.type == .video}) {
    let video = videoElement.item as! Video
    print(video.url)
}
```

Comment: I've dig up through your solution and it's really nice, but it doesn't solve my problem. You've used all three `enum` values, but in my case my app will only accept two of them, which in result will throw `corruptedData`, as it won't be able to decode enum correctly.

Comment: I updated the answer with a suggestion to filter the unwanted elements.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is to _simplify_ the JSON and tackle the problem from this side. I really like it, but I'm not sure whether this is the path I'd like to take. I may end up with `TypeItem` simplification of my type, but I'm not sure about this filtering.